# How Can I Use the Poppins Font on My Website (coded with HTML, CSS, and JavaScript)?

Tags: javascript, html, css, fonts

While working on a coding tutorial online, I noticed they used the Poppins font. They were working in the VS Code editor, just like me. But they had a different font than I did. It didn't mess up the program's functionality, but it didn't help its looks. Could someone guide me through what's wrong and give me a solution? Thanks so much!

I tried installing the Poppins font in my C:/Windows/Fonts directory, but it didn't work when I tried rerunning the script.

This isn't necessarily a programming question, but it is related and any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Easiest way: use Google Fonts; https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Poppins